# Clojure defining multimethods and how to pass parameters

Tags: clojure, multimethod

I seem to have a hard time understanding how the below code works. And more precisely how the defined function handles passed parameters

```
(defmulti encounter
    (fn [x y] [(:role x) (:role y)]))

(defmethod encounter [:manager :boss] [x y]
    :promise-unrealistic-deadlines)

(defmethod encounter [:manager :developer] [x y]
    :demand-overtime)
....
```

Why do we have 2 vectors (`[x y] [(:role x) (:role y)]`) when defining the "encounter". Does this mean that the function takes to vector parameter? If so why do I have to call the function like:

`(encounter {:role :manager} {:role :boss})`

Isn't  the above call passing the first hashmap to [x y] and the second to [(:role x) (:role y)]). I just can't understand how does **x** get the value :manager and **y** gets the value of :boss.

The above example is from here: https://yogthos.github.io/ClojureDistilled.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument passed to the `defmulti` macro is called a dispatch function. Here, it accepts two arguments, `x` and `y`, each of which is expected to be a map with a `:role` key in it. The value returned by the dispatch function is called a dispatch value. It is being compared against whenever you call `encounter`.

Every definition of the `encounter` method takes some dispatch value as its second argument. In your example, that value is produced by passing the arguments `x` and `y` into the dispatch function `(fn [x y] [(:role x) (:role y)])` inside `defmulti`. Depending on the value returned by that function, either a corresponding method is invoked, or an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown:

```
(encounter {:role :designer} {:role :developer})
```

produces

```
IllegalArgumentException No method in multimethod 'encounter' for dispatch value: [:designer :developer]  clojure.lang.MultiFn.getFn (MultiFn.java:156)
```

But adding a new possible dispatch value fixes it:

```
(defmethod encounter [:designer :developer] [x y]
  :discuss-video-games)

(encounter {:role :designer} {:role :developer})
=> :discuss-video-games
```

There's also a [dedicated clojuredocs page](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defmethod) with more good examples.